# MongoDB library missing for PHP 7.1 x64 NTS on Windows

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, php-7.1

I'm looking for the php_mongodb.dll extension for php 7.1 x64 NTS on Windows.

I know mongodb-driver is compatible with php 7.1, but I can't find the precompiled dll library for windows...

I tried to compile it on my own, but I'm not mastering C++ and I ran into issues that I could not resolve by myself.

I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) for the building process

I downloaded PHP 7.1 sources and binary for Windows [here](http://windows.php.net/qa/)

Can somebody please help me ? It would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 7.1 has not been released yet, and hence there are no official builds for it yet. However, you can find binaries build for PHP 7.1 and MongoDB driver 1.1.9 at http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/mongodb/1.1.9/